# How to process a list of space separated file type patterns in a loop?

Tags: batch-file, windows-scripting

So I'm making a batch file to do some backups of some old computers and am having quite a hard time printing the file types I'm trying to back up to the cmd prompt because whenever I run this it changes the text "*.png" into "myfile.png". So it's functioning like a wildcard even though I'm just trying to print "*.png"

Here is the code I have:

```
echo off
cls
set "SelectedFileTypes=*.pdf *.docx *.tif *.txt *.png *.xcf *.jpeg *.raw *.jpg *.mp3 *.mp4 *.m4a *.wmv *.msdvd *.itdb"
echo %SelectedFileTypes%
echo/
for %%I in (%SelectedFileTypes%) do echo %%I
pause
```

Here is the output I want:

```
*.pdf *.docx *.tif *.txt *.png *.xcf *.jpeg *.raw *.jpg *.mp3 *.mp4 *.m4a *.wmv *.msdvd *.itdb

*.pdf
*.docx
*.tif
*.txt
*.png
*.xcf
*.jpeg
*.raw
*.jpg
*.mp3
*.mp4
*.m4a
*.wmv
*.msdvd
*.itdb
```

Here is the output I get most of the time, it seems to be all the files that match in the directory I'm in.

```
*.pdf *.docx *.tif *.txt *.png *.xcf *.jpeg *.raw *.jpg *.mp3 *.mp4 *.m4a *.wmv *.msdvd *.itdb

A+Study.pdf
after.txt
before.txt
story of my life.txt
TshirtIdea.txt
bananaForScale.png
windows_logo.png
BadTree.xcf
7ed48ccf-5746-4c86-b5c4-8c02ba0ccbf9.jpg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output is correct for your batch code as command **FOR** without option `/F` interprets the list of file name patterns like command **DIR** and returns all file names matching any of the specified patterns.

Here is one example how to process the list of file name patterns in a loop as you obviously want.

```
@echo off
cls
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Define the file type patterns in a single space separated list.
set "SelectedFileTypes=*.pdf *.docx *.tif *.txt *.png *.xcf *.jpeg *.raw *.jpg *.mp3 *.mp4 *.m4a *.wmv *.msdvd *.itdb"

rem Append a space at end if there is not already a space at end.
if not "%SelectedFileTypes:~-1%" == " " set "SelectedFileTypes=%SelectedFileTypes% "

rem This loop is executed until all file type patterns are processed
rem determined by an empty string for the remaining file type patterns.
rem The FOR command returns the first pattern of the space separated
rem patterns and the string substitution removes this pattern and the
rem following space from the list of file name patterns.

:NextFileType
if "%SelectedFileTypes%" == "" goto Finished
for /F "tokens=1" %%# in ("%SelectedFileTypes%") do (
    set "FileType=%%#"
    set "SelectedFileTypes=!SelectedFileTypes:%%# =!"
)

rem Do here whatever should be done with this file type pattern.
echo File type is: %FileType%
goto NextFileType

:Finished
echo Processed all file types.
endlocal
pause
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `cls /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `pause /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

For other solutions look on list returned by running a Stack Overflow search with [[batch-file] split string](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+split+string) as search terms.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a sub-routine with `call` and pass the value of `SelectedFileTypes` as arguments to it. Together with `shift`, `if` and `goto` you can create a conditional loop, which returns every single item of `SelectedFileTypes`:

```
@echo off
cls
set "SelectedFileTypes=*.pdf *.docx *.tif *.txt *.png *.xcf *.jpeg *.raw *.jpg *.mp3 *.mp4 *.m4a *.wmv *.msdvd *.itdb"
echo(%SelectedFileTypes%
echo(
call :SUB %SelectedFileTypes%
pause
exit /B

:SUB
shift
if "%~0"=="" goto :EOF
echo(%~0
goto :SUB
```

The great advantage of this approach is that you do not have to do the parsing on your own but let the command interpreter do it, supporting the standard delimiters <kbd>SPACE</kbd>, <kbd>TAB</kbd>, `,`, `;` and `=`.